# Correct way to use PersianCalendar as Table column in entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ASP.NET Web API project in which i'm trying to store my date using Persian calendar. Here is my POCO class.

```
public class Person
{
    PersianCalendar p = new PersianCalendar();

    public Person()
    {

    }


    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, PersianCalendar birthDate)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        DateOfBirth = birthDate;
    }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public PersianCalendar DateOfBirth { get; set; }


}
```

I created a POST method for my API.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Person _p)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Persons.Add(_p);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var msg = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created,
                _p);
            msg.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri + _p.PersonId.ToString());
            return msg;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
    }
```

and i'm send my POST request using Fiddler.
[image]

but in the Chrome Dev Tools, break point  birthDate of my Person class is set to null.
[image]
Can anyone help me with what is wrong? 
How can i send my date in persian format??

Comment: Added a different way to my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DateOfBirth` in your model POCO should not be of type `PersianCalendar`. A calendar is used to manipulate `DateTime` objects, not as a container of `DateTime` objects.

Your model should store the date of birth as a normal `DateTime`, then you can use a `PersianCalendar` to manipulate it. The easy (but a bit ugly) way to do this is to have a `DateTime` field and a separate public `string` property for getting and setting the date as formatted by the Persian calendar:

```
public class Person
{
    PersianCalendar p = new PersianCalendar();
    public Person()
    {

    }
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime birthDate)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        DateOfBirth = birthDate;
    }
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, string birthDateString)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        DateOfBirthString = birthDateString;
    }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth;
    public string DateOfBirthString
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", p.GetYear(DateOfBirth), p.GetMonth(DateOfBirth), p.GetDayOfMonth(DateOfBirth));
        }
        set
        {
            var parts = value.Split('/');
            DateOfBirth = p.ToDateTime(int.Parse(parts[0]), int.Parse(parts[1]), int.Parse(parts[2]), 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that a `DateTime` represents a general specific moment in time. It does not have any *uniquely correct* string representation. But if you use something like what I have above, then you are kind of deciding that *for your application* the only correct string representation is a Persian date, formatted as `yyyy/MM/dd`.

---

**EDIT**: You can also create a custom JSON `JsonConverter` and use that in your model. Your POCO model could then look like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person() { }
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, DateTime birthDate)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        DateOfBirth = birthDate;
    }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(PersianDateConverter))]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth;
}
```

And the `PersianDateConverter` class looks like this:

```
public class PersianDateConverter : JsonConverter
{
    PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
    public PersianDateConverter()
    {

    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string persianDateString = reader.Value as string;
        if (persianDateString == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Error in PersionDateConverter.ReadJson: Got null string");

        var parts = persianDateString.Split('/');
        return pc.ToDateTime(int.Parse(parts[0]), int.Parse(parts[1]), int.Parse(parts[2]), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        DateTime d = (DateTime)value;
        string output = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", pc.GetYear(d), pc.GetMonth(d), pc.GetDayOfMonth(d));
        writer.WriteValue(output);
    }
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType.Name == "DateTime")
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Note**: This `PersianDateConverter` is not well tested for edge cases. Seems to work ok as long as the data it is manipulating is valid though.

Comment: tnx for replay but is there any better way to store this date as DateTime not String?